# Why does a substring with indexes [0, 1] return two characters, including the escape backslash?

Tags: ruby, string, escaping

I have:

```
long_string # => "\nIt was the best of times,\nIt was the worst of times.\n"
```

I get:

```
long_string[0,1] # => "\n"
```

I am curious why I get two characters rather than merely `"\"` as in other cases.

Is this how escaped characters are treated in substrings and beyond?

Comment: Are you sure `\n` is two characters, not just one newline character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation of [`String#[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)

> `str[start, length] → new_str or nil`
>
> If passed a `start` index and a `length`, returns a substring containing `length` characters starting at the `start` index

For example

```
"Hello"[0, 1] #=> "H"
'Hello'[0, 1] #=> "H"
```

But there is difference between single quotes and double quotes.

Double quotes allow for many escape sequences, e.g. `"\n"`, `"\t"`, `"\s"`, `"\r"` and others. All this is not two, but one character.

`"\n"` is just one (newline) character. But `'\n'` contains two characters (backslash and letter).

```
"\n".size #=> 1
'\n'.size #=> 2
```

Compare the different behavior of double quotes and single quotes when you try to return one character starting from zero index

```
"\n"[0, 1] #=> "\n"
'\n'[0, 1] #=> "\\"
```

As is clear from the above `"\\"` is just one character (backslash). Another backslash is used  to escape.

Answer (score 0):

Solved - flexible quotes as above store the string as `"\nIt was the best of times,\nIt was the worst of times.\n"` (in double quotes). Double quoted strings interpret escaped characters, whereas single quoted strings do not.

E.g.

```
string = "\n"
```

string.size == 1 in above

string.size == 2 in below

```
string = '\n'
```

Answer (score -6):

[0,1] will always return 2 characters - character 0 and character 1. [0,0] will return the first character.

Comment: That does not seem to be the case elsewhere in the koans e.g. ```assert_equal "I", long_string[0,1]``` for a single-lined version of the same text

Comment: `[0, 0]` returns empty string `""` and `[0,1]` returns 1 character